# Flutter Installation Problem - Android Licenses in Flutter Doctor

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, android-studio-electric-eel, android-licenses

I'm trying to install Flutter and can't seem to get through the part of accepting the Android licenses in flutter doctor. I keep getting this error when I try to run 'flutter doctor --android-licenses' in the command prompt.

```
C:\Users\anach>flutter doctor --android-licenses
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/prefs/AndroidLocationsProvider has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" Android sdkmanager tool was found, but failed to run (C:\Users\anach\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\cmdline-tools\latest\bin\sdkmanager.bat):
"exited code 1".
Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK,
visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions.
```

I've tried almost every solution including manually downloading the Android SDK Tools in Android Studio's SDK Manager but I still get the same error. I've read that people are experiencing the same problems when updating to Android Studio Electric Eel. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: The error message says, `AndroidLocationsProvider has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime`.  I think you may need to update Java on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if you have the Android SDK Command-Line Tools installed, you can check it in Android Studio under Appearance and Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK.

[Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mX9qU.png)

Comment: Yup I already have it installed. I've also re-installed Android Studio but the same error still show up

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Put this licenses folder in your Android SDK root [License folder](https://filetransfer.io/data-package/pQ9Ayeku#link) and then restart your IDE

Answer (score 0):

Download and install latest JDK (For me now is 20)
and Update environment variables.
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20
JDK_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20

good luck